# Updating kernel Version - Centos 7

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, centos

I want to update the kernel to the latest version or   atleast kernel-3.10.0-514.13.1.el7 . Current it shows the below kernel version in aws server.  Using linux centos 7.

Want to update the kernel version atleast kernel-3.10.0-514.13.1.el7

**Will  "yum  -y update kernel"  update to a latest kernel >=kernel-3.10.0-514.13.1.el7 ?**

```
uname -sr
Linux 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64

cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy/want to use the 'current' kernels then you can enable the `elrepo` and install `kernel-ml`

Check your `/etc/yum.repos.d/elrepo.repo` - If you don't have one then have a look at; http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php which will give you instructions on how to add and enable the enterprise linux repo and enable the kernel section.

You should then be able to upgrade all the way to 4.11.1 if you want. The kernel-ml installs are compatible with the old kernel-x files and can co-exist on a system. Kernel-ml also has the firmware, headers and libs files.

```
yum info kernel-ml

Name        : kernel-ml
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.11.1
Release     : 1.el6.elrepo
Size        : 184 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : elrepo-kernel
Summary     : The Linux kernel. (The core of any Linux-based operating system.)
URL         : https://www.kernel.org/
License     : GPLv2
Description : This package provides the Linux kernel (vmlinuz), the core of any
            : Linux-based operating system. The kernel handles the basic functions
            : of the OS: memory allocation, process allocation, device I/O, etc.
```

Once you have installed the new kernel you will need to check your `grub.conf` file which tells the OS which kernel (if you have several installed) to boot from. The file should be located at; `/etc/grub.conf` Somewhere towards the top of the file should be the line `default=x` where `x` is usually `0` or `1` Below that you may have a list of kernels. The 1st one in the list is usually the newest and is `0` they then number down the list.

Example `grub.conf` booting kernel 4.11.1-1;

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (4.11.1-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-4.11.1-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xs-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_xs/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=la
tarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_LVM_LV=vg_xs/lv_root rd_NO_DM audit=0
        initrd /initramfs-4.11.1-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.img
title CentOS (4.11.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-4.11.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xs-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_xs/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=la
tarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_LVM_LV=vg_xs/lv_root rd_NO_DM audit=0
        initrd /initramfs-4.11.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.img
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.    After yum install kernel-ml does the system point  automatically to new kernel once rebooted?

Comment: Sorry been away so only just seen this - I've updated my answer with the extra info on how to check which versions you have installed, and how to change which version is booted into. Depending how your system is setup it will either boot the newest kernel, or the last kernel - see above which will tell you how to check/change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that command will update the kernel and all of its dependencies. However, updating the kernel is only one part of your OS and it would be advisable to update your entire system using `yum update`, unless you have specific needs for certain package versions. I always leave out the `-y` option so I can review what's being updated/installed.